# Dynamic port forwarding reports connection failed and timeout

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm running a benchmark based on selenium to send requests to an application server. Since the application server is deployed on a private cloud, I'm not able to connect to the server from the benchmark. Therefore I'm using the Dynamic Port Forwarding (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding). I did the `ssh -C -D 1080 IP_AS` and set the corresponding socket in Firefox. As I run the benchmark, I notice that if the traffic is a bit high, I keep getting the following from the terminal opened with the `ssh -C -D`:

`channel 228: open failed; connect failed; Connection timed out.`

Could anyone help me on this by sending heavy traffic? Alternative solutions to send requests to the private cloud are also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

To **reliably** send a lot of traffic to a system under test you need to **put the client and server as close as possible.** The easiest way to do that is to put the client system on the **same network** as the server (unless you're testing the router or firewall).

Comment: I think they are quite close because they all have access to the college network. It's just that for the AS, the IP is not accessible from outside the private cloud.